# How to use Pandas split for retaining both parts of column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a file with columns such as:

```
 A    B                 C
f>g f=313/g=6535    1:123456
r>t r=2/t=7020      1:56789
g>f g=2/f=6764      1:65555
t>r t=5337/r=677    1:115675
```

and I am struggling with splitting them. I need not only to split them, but also save both parts of splitted column.

For third column, I tried this syntax

```
df['name_1'] = df['C'].str.split(':')[0]
df['name_2'] = df['C'].str.split(':')[1]
```

But still get `ValueError`

I have no more ideas left, what is wrong?
I checked previous questions, but no  thread seems to be answering this problem

Thank you!

Comment: try `df['C'].str.split(':').str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
df[['name_1', 'name_2']] = df['C'].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

Which results in what you want

```
     A             B         C name_1  name_2
0  f>g  f=313/g=6535  1:123456      1  123456
1  r>t    r=2/t=7020   1:56789      1   56789
2  g>f    g=2/f=6764   1:65555      1   65555
3  t>r  t=5337/r=677  1:115678      1  115678
```